# docs.google.com rendering e.g. for PDF not working (only) on Lollipop in webview

Tags: android, pdf, android-5.0-lollipop

I have some applications on Android for 2 year with unchanged code working perfectly to display PDF files on the fly in webview using prefix http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=

I just realized, that it is not working anymore after upgrading my phone on Lollipop or any another new device.
The same application works perfect on old devices.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

I tried also to use:

```
 https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=
```

Still the same result but only on my Samsung S5 Mini after upgrade to Lollipop and maybe more new devices.

Answer (score 0):

strange, but I fix it. Took me hours to find the problem, but it was in layout .xml file of webview. It was working perfectly until lollipop version and the problem was only with docs.google.com service webpage....